# How to delete Field From Shapefile by Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I am using the following code to delete a field from a shapefile but I am getting an error!

```
def main():
    # Import arcpy module
   import arcpy

# Local variables:
   point_shp = "G:\\Temp\\All_Provinces.shp"

# Process: Add Field
   #arcpy.AddField_management(point_shp, "NEWFIELD", "TEXT", "", "", "25", "", "NON_NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

   arcpy.DeleteField_management(point_shp,NEWFIELD)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The error is all important.  Can you edit your question and post it?

Answer (score 3):

ok error was on

```
arcpy.DeleteField_management(point_shp,NEWFIELD)
```

must be

```
arcpy.DeleteField_management(point_shp,"NEWFIELD")
```